# Declare variables types for python function triggers invalid syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am having trouble why I am getting an invalid syntax error when I declare what my variable is inside my function. The function works when I step through it in python, but not when I try to run the program from the command line.

command line code:

```
python filename.py
```

python code:

```
import pandas as pd
def my_func(df:pd.DataFrame,name:str):
    print("Hello world")
def main():
    my_func(df=pd.DataFrame(),name='name')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.9.9. What's your Python version?

Comment: @richardec exactly this. They may be using a really old 3.x, or (more likely), `python` resolves to python-2.x.

Comment: Confirm that it works fine on Python 3.8. It may be that your version does not support typing, with is supported since Python 3.5 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: I can confirm it works on Python 3.6.9

Comment: User error. I never set the PATH variable. Was typing python filename.py and not python3 filename.py.

Comment: You didn't even share the error and how you run it from the command line. Many people wasted time, do you agree? Please consider it for your possible next queries. (Oh, the below "answer" gets reputation maybe that's a win because it should've been a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. Check your Python version - you're probably using a version that doesn't support type hints, such as Python 2.

(Perhaps `python` resolves to `python2`?)